# How can I pass my class instance to the AIogram handlers for subsequent actions?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiogram

I'm trying to create an asynchronous application that will be controlled via aiogram.

To do this I created the `AsyncioManager` class:

```
class AsyncioManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = []

    def add_task(self, coroutine):
        self.tasks.append(coroutine)

    async def run_all_tasks(self):
        await asyncio.gather(*self.tasks)

    async def console_menu(self):
        while True:
            code = await asyncio.to_thread(input, 'Code? ')
            elif code == 'tasks':
                print(self.tasks)
            elif code == 'exit':
                break

    async def main(self):
        self.add_task(self.console_menu())
        await self.run_all_tasks()
```

Then I run this class in the main file:

```
manager = AsyncioManager()
manager.add_task(start())
manager.add_task(aiogram_bot.main(manager))
asyncio.run(manager.main())
```

In the `start()` function I have implemented receiving some information using sockets, this is not so important. The aiogram bot itself looks like this:

```
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.enums.parse_mode import ParseMode
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiorgramcode.handlers import bot_messages, user_commands
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext

bot = Bot(token=TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
dp = Dispatcher(storage=MemoryStorage())

async def main(manager: asyncio_manager.AsyncioManager):
    dp.include_router(bot_messages.router)
    dp.startup.register(on_startup)
    dp.shutdown.register(on_shutdown)
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot, allowed_updates=dp.resolve_used_update_types())
```

As you can see, I'm trying to pass the manager and receive it in the main. But I don’t understand how to continue to work and transfer it to the routers. I import routes, they are stored in separate files:

```
from aiorgramcode.handlers import bot_messages, user_commands
```

I want to use functionality in routes to add new tasks, i.e. use `manager.add_task(some_coro())` for example.

```
async def example():
    print(1)
    asyncio.sleep(1)

@router.message(CommandStart())
async def start_handler(msg: Message):
    await msg.answer(f"Привет! Выбери действие", reply_markup=reply.main_kb)
    # await manager.add_task(example())
```

How can this be implemented? May it be necessary to implement the entire structure differently?